# Access object with in array

Tags: php, arrays

```
Array
(
[0] => Contact Object
    (
[id] => 1
[status] => ACTIVE
[first_name] => Ahmed
[middle_name] => 
[last_name] => Taibah
[confirmed] => 
[source] => 
[email_addresses] => Array
(
[0] => EmailAddress Object
(
[id] => 1
[status] => ACTIVE
[confirm_status] => NO_CONFIRMATION_REQUIRED
[opt_in_source] => ACTION_BY_OWNER
[opt_in_date] => 2009-07-23T05:54:30.315Z
[opt_out_date] => 
[email_address] => info@test.sa
)
)
```

How can  i get the value of [confirm_status] as this is under object then array then again object then this index value i need.

Comment: That would be something like foreach ($array as $key => $value) echo $value['confirm_status'];

Comment: I would disagree on that.. the usage of this should become: $value[0]->confirm_status .. u r looping only 1 time. so U get $value to hold the values of the 1st Contact Object.. either edit or remove

Answer (score 5):

```
$arr[0]->email_addresses[0]->confirm_status
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$contact[0]->email_addresses[0]->confirm_status
```

You can do something like this.

Comment: it's the same as comment up

Answer (score 0):

You can use this like

```
$confirm_status = $arr['email_addresses'][0]->confirm_status;
```